# Can NSUserDefaults work across different code bases?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.forms, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to share data between an objective c iOS appliation and a c# xamarin forms application using app groups.

I am setting up the initial data in the objective c project and passing the data using the shared data "clipboard" available for app groups.

This is my objective c code that initializes and posts the string.

```
NSString *appGroupId = @"group.sample";
NSUserDefaults *groupUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:appGroupId];
[groupUserDefaults setValue:offlineMsg forKey:@"RunwayRequest"];
[groupUserDefaults synchronize];
```

This is my c# code in a Xamarin.Forms application.

```
string groupName = "group.sample";
NSUserDefaults shared = new    NSUserDefaults();
shared.AddSuite(groupName);
```

var test = shared.ValueForKey((NSString)"RunwayRequest");

It is always returning a null values but I think I am adding the string to the shared folder, but I am unable to retrieve the data in the other project.

I have added the app group identifier to both provisioning profiles. I don't think I have to add anything to the plist file but I am not positive.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with plist file, the AppGroup ID is unique already. Define UserDefault with suiteName (not standard) and get/set normally.

Comment: I defined using suite name for both do you see any issues with the code?

Comment: Though there is no need to add anything to info.plist, you should add the key into Entitlements.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you don't have to add anything into *info.plist*. But there are also some details.

**First**, you should enable [App Group Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/app-groups-capabilities) for both iOS apps on **Apple Developer portal**.

To sum up,

1. Create a App Group, suppose the Identifier is *group.sample*.
2. Create an App ID for each app separately, enable App Group Capabilities and add each App ID in the App Group.
3. Generate a Provisioning Profiles for each app separately. Don't forget to  include the correct Certificate and physical devices you want to deploy in Profiles.

**Second**, add a key value for Entitlements.plist for each app. For more info, you could refer to [App Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/entitlements?tabs=macos#app-groups).

After the above steps, you could deploy the each app on your iOS device and share the data with app group now.

Hope it helps!